# Bind data to a Model in a View using JQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In a ASP.NET MVC View written in Razor, how do you bind data to a Model using JQuery's $.getJSON or $.ajax?

Can the view be written something like this? -

```
@model MyModel
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")/', function (dataReturned) { 
    @model = dataReturned  //something like this? 
                           //how can you put the data into the Model?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix client code with server code, this will never work. What are you trying to do? Create ajax request to server and retrieve json? Now your code looks strange, render html on server, then get json data from client and re-render server code on client?

Comment: Thanks webdeveloper! I was trying to find a way to to use ajax to get (and also post) and refresh a webpage while also binding to the Model.